# javascript Regular Expression and Replace

Tags: javascript, regex, variables, replace, tags

how can i replace

```
<em>Rs</em> 154,451. Hello world
```

to

```
<b>Rs 154,451</b>. Hello world
```

via JavaScript Regular Expression.

```
/<em>Rs<\/em> [0-9,]*/ig
```

is regular expression to find `<em>Rs</em> 154,451`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `()` to capture a match and later use it in the replace:

```
var s = "<em>Rs</em> 154,451. Hello world";
s.replace(/<em>Rs<\/em>([^.]+)/, '<b>Rs$1</b>')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
myString = "<em>Rs</em> 154,451. Hello world";
output = myString.replace(/<em>Rs<\/em>\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)/g, "<b>Rs $1</b>");
```

Comment: it is returning Rs $1